# Решить проблему с заменой текста на JSX

Tags: javascript, reactjs, регулярные-выражения, typescript, markdown

Первая проблема это отступ между списками, почему он появляется? Если дописать в конец регулярки `\n?` *(нажимаем чекбокс)*, тогда его нет, но и чтобы появился между последним списком и текстом отступ, придется писать две строки.

```js
var isRegExp = function (re)
{
  return re instanceof RegExp;
};
var escapeRegExp = function escapeRegExp(string)
{
    var reRegExpChar = /[\\^$.*+?()[\]{}|]/g,
        reHasRegExpChar = RegExp(reRegExpChar.source);

    return (string && reHasRegExpChar.test(string))
        ? string.replace(reRegExpChar, '\\$&')
        : string;
};
var isString = function (value)
{
    return typeof value === 'string';
};
var flatten = function (array)
{
    var newArray = [];

    array.forEach(function (item)
    {
        if (Array.isArray(item))
        {
            newArray = newArray.concat(item);
        } else
        {
            newArray.push(item);
        }
    });

    return newArray;
};
function replaceString(str, match, fn)
{
    var curCharStart = 0;
    var curCharLen = 0;

    if (str === '')
    {
        return str;
    } else if (!str || !isString(str))
    {
        throw new TypeError('First argument to react-string-replace#replaceString must be a string');
    }

    var re = match;

    if (!isRegExp(re))
    {
        re = new RegExp('(' + escapeRegExp(re) + ')', 'gi');
    }

    var result = str.split(re);

    for (var i = 1, length = result.length; i < length; i += 2)
    {
        if (result[ i ] === undefined || result[ i - 1 ] === undefined)
        {
            console.warn('reactStringReplace: Encountered undefined value during string replacement. Your RegExp may not be working the way you expect.');
            continue;
        }

        curCharLen = result[ i ].length;
        curCharStart += result[ i - 1 ].length;
        result[ i ] = fn(result[ i ], i, curCharStart);
        curCharStart += curCharLen;
    }

    return result;
}

function reactStringReplace(source, match, fn)
{
    if (!Array.isArray(source)) source = [ source ];

    return flatten(source.map(function (x)
    {
        return isString(x) ? replaceString(x, match, fn) : x;
    }));
}

function randomKey(): string
{
    return Date.now() + "" + Math.random();
}

function _wrappedItalic(match: string): ReactNode
{
    return <em key={randomKey()}>{match}</em>;
}

function _wrappedBold(match: string): ReactNode
{
    return <strong key={randomKey()}>{match}</strong>;
}

function _wrappedBoldAndItalic(match: string): ReactNode
{
    return <em key={randomKey()}><strong>{match}</strong></em>;
}

function _wrappedList(match: string): ReactNode
{
    const items: string[] = match.trim().split(/\n|\\n/g)
        .map((item) => item.replace(/^-\s+/, "").trim())
        .filter((item) => item.trim() !== "");

    return (
        <ul style={{ margin: 0 }} key={randomKey()}>
            {items.map((item) => <li key={item}>{item}</li>)}
        </ul>
    );
}

function _wrappedOrderedList(match: string): ReactNode
{
    const items: string[] = match.trim().split(/\n|\\n/g)
        .map((item) => item.replace(/^\d+\.\s+/, "").trim())
        .filter((item) => item.trim() !== "");

    return (
        <ol style={{ margin: 0 }} key={randomKey()}>
            {items.map((item) => <li key={item}>{item}</li>)}
        </ol>
    );
}

function convertMarkdown(text: string | ReactNodeArray | undefined): ReactNodeArray
{
    // Bold and Italic
    text = reactStringReplace(text, /___(.*?)___/g, _wrappedBoldAndItalic);
    text = reactStringReplace(text, /\*\*\*(.*?)\*\*\*/g, _wrappedBoldAndItalic);
    text = reactStringReplace(text, /__\*(.*?)\*__/g, _wrappedBoldAndItalic);
    text = reactStringReplace(text, /\*\*_(.*?)_\*\*/g, _wrappedBoldAndItalic);

    // Bold
    text = reactStringReplace(text, /\*\*(.*?)\*\*/g, _wrappedBold);
    text = reactStringReplace(text, /__(.*?)__/g, _wrappedBold);

    // Italic
    text = reactStringReplace(text, /\*(.*?)\*/g, _wrappedItalic);
    text = reactStringReplace(text, /_(.*?)_/g, _wrappedItalic);

    // Unordered Lists
    text = reactStringReplace(text, /((?:^-\s+.*\n?)+)(?=\n|$)/gm, _wrappedList);

    // Ordered Lists
    text = reactStringReplace(text, /((?:^\d+\.\s+.*\n?)+)(?=\n|$)/gm, _wrappedOrderedList);

    // Line break
    text = reactStringReplace(text, /(\n|\\n)/g, () => (<br key={randomKey()} />));

    return text;
}

function convertMarkdownTwo(text: string | ReactNodeArray | undefined): ReactNodeArray
{
    // Bold and Italic
    text = reactStringReplace(text, /___(.*?)___/g, _wrappedBoldAndItalic);
    text = reactStringReplace(text, /\*\*\*(.*?)\*\*\*/g, _wrappedBoldAndItalic);
    text = reactStringReplace(text, /__\*(.*?)\*__/g, _wrappedBoldAndItalic);
    text = reactStringReplace(text, /\*\*_(.*?)_\*\*/g, _wrappedBoldAndItalic);

    // Bold
    text = reactStringReplace(text, /\*\*(.*?)\*\*/g, _wrappedBold);
    text = reactStringReplace(text, /__(.*?)__/g, _wrappedBold);

    // Italic
    text = reactStringReplace(text, /\*(.*?)\*/g, _wrappedItalic);
    text = reactStringReplace(text, /_(.*?)_/g, _wrappedItalic);

    // Unordered Lists
    text = reactStringReplace(text, /((?:^-\s+.*\n?)+)(?=\n|$)\n?/gm, _wrappedList);

    // Ordered Lists
    text = reactStringReplace(text, /((?:^\d+\.\s+.*\n?)+)(?=\n|$)\n?/gm, _wrappedOrderedList);

    // Line break
    text = reactStringReplace(text, /(\n|\\n)/g, () => (<br key={randomKey()} />));

    return text;
}

const { useState } = React;

function App()
{
    const [isCheckbox, setIsCheckbox] = useState(false);
    const [text, setText] = useState("It’s up to you how you complete the quest. We recommend to complete **one mission per week** for the best results.\n\n- list item 1\n- list item 2\n- list item 3\n0. item 1\n0. item 2\n0. item 3\n- list item 1\n- list item 2\n- list item 3\n0. item 1\n0. item 2\n0. item 3\n\nIt will allow you enough time to digest your reflections without losing your momentum.")

    return (
        <div style={{width: "70%"}}>
            <div style={{marginBottom: "15px"}}>
                <textarea
                    style={{width: "100%"}}
                    rows={6}
                    value={text}
                    onChange={
                        ({target}: ChangeEvent<HTMLTextAreaElement>) =>
                        {
                            setText(target.value);
                        }
                    }
                />
            </div>

            Preview: <label><input type="checkbox" checked={isCheckbox} onChange={({target}: ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => setIsCheckbox(target.checked)} />\n?</label>
            <hr />
            {isCheckbox === false ? convertMarkdown(text) : convertMarkdownTwo(text)}
        </div>
    );
}


// Рендеринг
ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('root')).render(<App/>);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/18.0.0/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/18.0.0/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>

<div id="root"></div>
```

---

Следующая проблема заключается в следующем, если я захочу в списке выделить какое-то слово курсивом/жирным/курсив и жирный, тогда текст переносится и создается несколько списков, почему это происходит и как исправить?

```js
var isRegExp = function (re)
{
  return re instanceof RegExp;
};
var escapeRegExp = function escapeRegExp(string)
{
    var reRegExpChar = /[\\^$.*+?()[\]{}|]/g,
        reHasRegExpChar = RegExp(reRegExpChar.source);

    return (string && reHasRegExpChar.test(string))
        ? string.replace(reRegExpChar, '\\$&')
        : string;
};
var isString = function (value)
{
    return typeof value === 'string';
};
var flatten = function (array)
{
    var newArray = [];

    array.forEach(function (item)
    {
        if (Array.isArray(item))
        {
            newArray = newArray.concat(item);
        } else
        {
            newArray.push(item);
        }
    });

    return newArray;
};
function replaceString(str, match, fn)
{
    var curCharStart = 0;
    var curCharLen = 0;

    if (str === '')
    {
        return str;
    } else if (!str || !isString(str))
    {
        throw new TypeError('First argument to react-string-replace#replaceString must be a string');
    }

    var re = match;

    if (!isRegExp(re))
    {
        re = new RegExp('(' + escapeRegExp(re) + ')', 'gi');
    }

    var result = str.split(re);

    for (var i = 1, length = result.length; i < length; i += 2)
    {
        if (result[ i ] === undefined || result[ i - 1 ] === undefined)
        {
            console.warn('reactStringReplace: Encountered undefined value during string replacement. Your RegExp may not be working the way you expect.');
            continue;
        }

        curCharLen = result[ i ].length;
        curCharStart += result[ i - 1 ].length;
        result[ i ] = fn(result[ i ], i, curCharStart);
        curCharStart += curCharLen;
    }

    return result;
}

function reactStringReplace(source, match, fn)
{
    if (!Array.isArray(source)) source = [ source ];

    return flatten(source.map(function (x)
    {
        return isString(x) ? replaceString(x, match, fn) : x;
    }));
}

function randomKey(): string
{
    return Date.now() + "" + Math.random();
}

function _wrappedItalic(match: string): ReactNode
{
    return <em key={randomKey()}>{match}</em>;
}

function _wrappedBold(match: string): ReactNode
{
    return <strong key={randomKey()}>{match}</strong>;
}

function _wrappedBoldAndItalic(match: string): ReactNode
{
    return <em key={randomKey()}><strong>{match}</strong></em>;
}

function _wrappedList(match: string): ReactNode
{
    const items: string[] = match.trim().split(/\n|\\n/g)
        .map((item) => item.replace(/^-\s+/, "").trim())
        .filter((item) => item.trim() !== "");

    return (
        <ul style={{ margin: 0 }} key={randomKey()}>
            {items.map((item) => <li key={item}>{item}</li>)}
        </ul>
    );
}

function _wrappedOrderedList(match: string): ReactNode
{
    const items: string[] = match.trim().split(/\n|\\n/g)
        .map((item) => item.replace(/^\d+\.\s+/, "").trim())
        .filter((item) => item.trim() !== "");

    return (
        <ol style={{ margin: 0 }} key={randomKey()}>
            {items.map((item) => <li key={item}>{item}</li>)}
        </ol>
    );
}

function convertMarkdown(text: string | ReactNodeArray | undefined): ReactNodeArray
{
    // Bold and Italic
    text = reactStringReplace(text, /___(.*?)___/g, _wrappedBoldAndItalic);
    text = reactStringReplace(text, /\*\*\*(.*?)\*\*\*/g, _wrappedBoldAndItalic);
    text = reactStringReplace(text, /__\*(.*?)\*__/g, _wrappedBoldAndItalic);
    text = reactStringReplace(text, /\*\*_(.*?)_\*\*/g, _wrappedBoldAndItalic);

    // Bold
    text = reactStringReplace(text, /\*\*(.*?)\*\*/g, _wrappedBold);
    text = reactStringReplace(text, /__(.*?)__/g, _wrappedBold);

    // Italic
    text = reactStringReplace(text, /\*(.*?)\*/g, _wrappedItalic);
    text = reactStringReplace(text, /_(.*?)_/g, _wrappedItalic);

    // Unordered Lists
    text = reactStringReplace(text, /((?:^-\s+.*\n?)+)(?=\n|$)\n?/gm, _wrappedList);

    // Ordered Lists
    text = reactStringReplace(text, /((?:^\d+\.\s+.*\n?)+)(?=\n|$)\n?/gm, _wrappedOrderedList);

    // Line break
    text = reactStringReplace(text, /(\n|\\n)/g, () => (<br key={randomKey()} />));

    return text;
}

const { useState } = React;

function App()
{
    const [text, setText] = useState("It’s up to you how you complete the quest. We recommend to complete **one mission per week** for the best results.\n\n- list item 1\n- list **item** bold 2\n- list item 3\n0. item 1\n0. item 2\n0. item 3\n- list item 1\n- list item 2\n- list item 3\n0. item 1\n0. item 2\n0. item 3\n\nIt will allow you enough time to digest your reflections without losing your momentum.")

    return (
        <div style={{width: "70%"}}>
            <div style={{marginBottom: "15px"}}>
                <textarea
                    style={{width: "100%"}}
                    rows={6}
                    value={text}
                    onChange={
                        ({target}: ChangeEvent<HTMLTextAreaElement>) =>
                        {
                            setText(target.value);
                        }
                    }
                />
            </div>

            Preview:
            <hr />
            {convertMarkdown(text)}
        </div>
    );
}


// Рендеринг
ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('root')).render(<App/>);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/18.0.0/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/18.0.0/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>

<div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: Пожалуйста старайтесь оставлять только те части кода, которые нужны. Слишком большие куски кода очень трудно отлаживать

Comment: @EzioMercer, тут и так только нужный код по МОЕМУ мнению.

Comment: Как минимум `convertMarkdown` и `convertMarkdown2` - это почти одно и то же. Я не очень понял первый вопрос ваш, вы описали проблему и вроде как сами же дали решение как его решить, в чем там конкретно вопрос, что нужно сделать?

Comment: В `convertMarkdown` есть проблема из-за того, что между списками появляется пустая строка, почему? `convertMarkdown2` вроде как исправляет это, но появляется проблема, что нужно делать две пустые строки после списка, чтобы появился отступ между списком и текстом.

Comment: "проблема из-за того, что между списками появляется пустая строка" - почему это проблема? Так и должно быть. Я сейчас проверил и [по картинке](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gVl7R.png) можете увидеть что расстояние между списками больше чем между элементами списка

Comment: Уберите пустую строку между списками, проблема вылезет во всей красе)

Comment: Эту пустую строку я поставил просто так для читабельности, но и без него всё равботает как и до этого https://i.stack.imgur.com/v3Yxs.png

Comment: Хорошо, возможно в MD это реализовано так. Но моя задача сделать, чтобы разные списки находились без промежутка (если нет между ними линии).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ответ на первый вопрос: надо убрать `(?=\n|$)` из регулярки. Я не до конца разобрался, если честно, но насколько я понял эта вещь создавала ещё одну группу для `match` и потому образовывались пустые строки

```js
function randomKey(): string
{
    return Date.now() + "" + Math.random();
}

function _wrappedItalic(match: string): ReactNode
{
    return <em key={randomKey()}>{match}</em>;
}

function _wrappedBold(match: string): ReactNode
{
    return <strong key={randomKey()}>{match}</strong>;
}

function _wrappedBoldAndItalic(match: string): ReactNode
{
    return <em key={randomKey()}><strong>{match}</strong></em>;
}

function _wrappedList(match: string): ReactNode
{
    const items: string[] = match.trim().split(/\n|\\n/g)
        .map((item) => item.replace(/^-\s+/, "").trim())
        .filter((item) => item.trim() !== "");

    return (
        <ul style={{ margin: 0 }} key={randomKey()}>
            {items.map((item) => <li key={item}>{item}</li>)}
        </ul>
    );
}

function _wrappedOrderedList(match: string): ReactNode
{
    const items: string[] = match.trim().split(/\n|\\n/g)
        .map((item) => item.replace(/^\d+\.\s+/, "").trim())
        .filter((item) => item.trim() !== "");

    return (
        <ol style={{ margin: 0 }} key={randomKey()}>
            {items.map((item) => <li key={item}>{item}</li>)}
        </ol>
    );
}

function convertMarkdown(text: string | ReactNodeArray | undefined): ReactNodeArray
{
    // Bold and Italic
    text = reactStringReplace(text, /___(.*?)___/g, _wrappedBoldAndItalic);
    text = reactStringReplace(text, /\*\*\*(.*?)\*\*\*/g, _wrappedBoldAndItalic);
    text = reactStringReplace(text, /__\*(.*?)\*__/g, _wrappedBoldAndItalic);
    text = reactStringReplace(text, /\*\*_(.*?)_\*\*/g, _wrappedBoldAndItalic);

    // Bold
    text = reactStringReplace(text, /\*\*(.*?)\*\*/g, _wrappedBold);
    text = reactStringReplace(text, /__(.*?)__/g, _wrappedBold);

    // Italic
    text = reactStringReplace(text, /\*(.*?)\*/g, _wrappedItalic);
    text = reactStringReplace(text, /_(.*?)_/g, _wrappedItalic);

    // Unordered Lists
    text = reactStringReplace(text, /((?:^-\s+.*\n?)+)/gm, _wrappedList);

    // Ordered Lists
    text = reactStringReplace(text, /((?:^\d+\.\s+.*\n?)+)/gm, _wrappedOrderedList);

    // Line break
    text = reactStringReplace(text, /(\n|\\n)/g, () => (<br key={randomKey()} />));

    return text;
}

const { useState } = React;

function App() {
    const [text, setText] = useState("It’s up to you how you complete the quest. We recommend to complete **one mission per week** for the best results.\n\n- list item 1\n- list item 2\n- list item 3\n0. item 1\n0. item 2\n0. item 3\n- list item 1\n- list item 2\n- list item 3\n0. item 1\n0. item 2\n0. item 3\n\nIt will allow you enough time to digest your reflections without losing your momentum.")

    return (
        <div style={{width: "70%"}}>
            <div style={{marginBottom: "15px"}}>
                <textarea
                    style={{width: "100%"}}
                    rows={6}
                    value={text}
                    onChange={
                        ({target}: ChangeEvent<HTMLTextAreaElement>) =>
                        {
                            setText(target.value);
                        }
                    }
                />
            </div>
            {convertMarkdown(text)}
        </div>
    );
}


// Рендеринг
ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('root')).render(<App/>);

var isRegExp = function (re)
{
  return re instanceof RegExp;
};
var escapeRegExp = function escapeRegExp(string)
{
    var reRegExpChar = /[\\^$.*+?()[\]{}|]/g,
        reHasRegExpChar = RegExp(reRegExpChar.source);

    return (string && reHasRegExpChar.test(string))
        ? string.replace(reRegExpChar, '\\$&')
        : string;
};
var isString = function (value)
{
    return typeof value === 'string';
};
var flatten = function (array)
{
    var newArray = [];

    array.forEach(function (item)
    {
        if (Array.isArray(item))
        {
            newArray = newArray.concat(item);
        } else
        {
            newArray.push(item);
        }
    });

    return newArray;
};
function replaceString(str, match, fn)
{
    var curCharStart = 0;
    var curCharLen = 0;

    if (str === '')
    {
        return str;
    } else if (!str || !isString(str))
    {
        throw new TypeError('First argument to react-string-replace#replaceString must be a string');
    }

    var re = match;

    if (!isRegExp(re))
    {
        re = new RegExp('(' + escapeRegExp(re) + ')', 'gi');
    }

    var result = str.split(re);

    for (var i = 1, length = result.length; i < length; i += 2)
    {
        if (result[ i ] === undefined || result[ i - 1 ] === undefined)
        {
            console.warn('reactStringReplace: Encountered undefined value during string replacement. Your RegExp may not be working the way you expect.');
            continue;
        }

        curCharLen = result[ i ].length;
        curCharStart += result[ i - 1 ].length;
        result[ i ] = fn(result[ i ], i, curCharStart);
        curCharStart += curCharLen;
    }

    return result;
}

function reactStringReplace(source, match, fn)
{
    if (!Array.isArray(source)) source = [ source ];

    return flatten(source.map(function (x)
    {
        return isString(x) ? replaceString(x, match, fn) : x;
    }));
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/18.0.0/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/18.0.0/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>

<div id="root"></div>
```

Ответ на второй вопрос: <s>***отвратительная библиотека***</s> проблема в том, что после очередного форматирования текст попадает в поле `children` объекта обозначающего какой-то тег, а в самом начале библиотеки написано, что если элемент массива - это не строка, то просто возращать его, а если строка, то работать с ним. Потому возникает острая необходимость в рекурсивном вызвозе библиотеки самой себя

1. Потому я переписал его изначальный функционал и получилось так:

   ```
    function reactStringReplace(source, match, fn) {
      if (!Array.isArray(source)) source = [source];

      return flatten(source.map(function(x) {
        if (isString(x)) return replaceString(x, match, fn);

        const children = x.props.children;

        if (isString(children)) x.props.children = reactStringReplace(children);      

        if (Array.isArray(children)) x.props.children = children.map(child => reactStringReplace(child, match, fn));

        return x;
      }));
    }
   ```

   Там ещё бывают случаи, когда `children` - это просто объект, но посмотрев через консоль я увидел что я не попадаю в эти случаи, потому не стал обрабатывать это, но возможно вам в дальнейшем надо будет это сделать для других случаев
2. Первый пункт частично решил проблему, в некоторых местах всё ещё были необработанные звёздочки, опять через консоль посмотрев, я увидел что иногда (честно не понял почему) строка типа `***item***` делится на `<strong>*item</strong>*` и из-за того что одна звезда остаётся за `strong`, то при обработке для `Italic` она работает не корректно т.к. эта строка хранится как

   ```
   [
     {
       key: 'strong',
       props: {
         children: ['* item']
       }
     },
     '*'
   ]
   ```

   И такую структуру он ясно что не сможет обработать для `Italic`. Там ещё странности были, но не запомнил если четсно, простите :) Решило проблему перенос обработки спиков раньше всех

   ```
   function convertMarkdown(text: string | ReactNodeArray | undefined): ReactNodeArray { 
     // Unordered Lists
     text = reactStringReplace(text, /((?:^-\s+.*\n?)+)/gm, _wrappedList);

     // Ordered Lists
     text = reactStringReplace(text, /((?:^\d+\.\s+.*\n?)+)/gm, _wrappedOrderedList);

     // Bold and Italic
     text = reactStringReplace(text, /___(.*?)___/g, _wrappedBoldAndItalic);
     text = reactStringReplace(text, /\*\*\*(.*?)\*\*\*/g, _wrappedBoldAndItalic);
     text = reactStringReplace(text, /__\*(.*?)\*__/g, _wrappedBoldAndItalic);
     text = reactStringReplace(text, /\*\*_(.*?)_\*\*/g, _wrappedBoldAndItalic);

     // Bold
     text = reactStringReplace(text, /\*\*(.*?)\*\*/g, _wrappedBold);
     text = reactStringReplace(text, /__(.*?)__/g, _wrappedBold);

     // Italic
     text = reactStringReplace(text, /\*(.*?)\*/g, _wrappedItalic);
     text = reactStringReplace(text, /_(.*?)_/g, _wrappedItalic);

     // Line break
     text = reactStringReplace(text, /(\n|\\n)/g, () => (<br key={randomKey()} />));

     return text;
   }
   ```

   ```js
   function randomKey(): string
   {
       return Date.now() + "" + Math.random();
   }

   function _wrappedItalic(match: string): ReactNode
   {
       return <em key={randomKey()}>{match}</em>;
   }

   function _wrappedBold(match: string): ReactNode
   {
       return <strong key={randomKey()}>{match}</strong>;
   }

   function _wrappedBoldAndItalic(match: string): ReactNode
   {
       return <em key={randomKey()}><strong>{match}</strong></em>;
   }

   function _wrappedList(match: string): ReactNode
   {
       const items: string[] = match.trim().split(/\n|\\n/g)
           .map((item) => item.replace(/^-\s+/, "").trim())
           .filter((item) => item.trim() !== "");

       return (
           <ul style={{ margin: 0 }} key={randomKey()}>
               {items.map((item) => <li key={item}>{item}</li>)}
           </ul>
       );
   }

   function _wrappedOrderedList(match: string): ReactNode
   {
       const items: string[] = match.trim().split(/\n|\\n/g)
           .map((item) => item.replace(/^\d+\.\s+/, "").trim())
           .filter((item) => item.trim() !== "");

       return (
           <ol style={{ margin: 0 }} key={randomKey()}>
               {items.map((item) => <li key={item}>{item}</li>)}
           </ol>
       );
   }

   function convertMarkdown(text: string | ReactNodeArray | undefined): ReactNodeArray { 
       // Unordered Lists
       text = reactStringReplace(text, /((?:^-\s+.*\n?)+)/gm, _wrappedList);

       // Ordered Lists
       text = reactStringReplace(text, /((?:^\d+\.\s+.*\n?)+)/gm, _wrappedOrderedList);
       
       // Bold and Italic
       text = reactStringReplace(text, /___(.*?)___/g, _wrappedBoldAndItalic);
       text = reactStringReplace(text, /\*\*\*(.*?)\*\*\*/g, _wrappedBoldAndItalic);
       text = reactStringReplace(text, /__\*(.*?)\*__/g, _wrappedBoldAndItalic);
       text = reactStringReplace(text, /\*\*_(.*?)_\*\*/g, _wrappedBoldAndItalic);

       // Bold
       text = reactStringReplace(text, /\*\*(.*?)\*\*/g, _wrappedBold);
       text = reactStringReplace(text, /__(.*?)__/g, _wrappedBold);

       // Italic
       text = reactStringReplace(text, /\*(.*?)\*/g, _wrappedItalic);
       text = reactStringReplace(text, /_(.*?)_/g, _wrappedItalic);
       
       // Line break
       text = reactStringReplace(text, /(\n|\\n)/g, () => (<br key={randomKey()} />));

       return text;
   }

   const { useState } = React;

   function App() {
       const [text, setText] = useState("It’s up to you how you complete the quest. We recommend to complete **one mission per week** for the best results.\n\n- list item 1\n- list *item* bold 2\n- list item 3\n0. **item** 4\n0. item 5\n0. item 6\n- list ***item*** 7\n- list item 8\n- list item 9\n0. item 10\n0. item 11\n0. item 12\n\nIt will allow you enough time to digest your reflections without losing your momentum.")

       return (
           <div style={{width: "70%"}}>
               <div style={{marginBottom: "15px"}}>
                   <textarea
                       style={{width: "100%"}}
                       rows={6}
                       value={text}
                       onChange={
                           ({target}: ChangeEvent<HTMLTextAreaElement>) =>
                           {
                               setText(target.value);
                           }
                       }
                   />
               </div>

               Preview:
               <hr />
               {convertMarkdown(text)}
           </div>
       );
   }


   // Рендеринг
   ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('root')).render(<App/>);

   var isRegExp = function (re) {
     return re instanceof RegExp;
   };

   var isString = function (value) {
       return typeof value === 'string';
   };

   var escapeRegExp = function escapeRegExp(string) {
       var reRegExpChar = /[\\^$.*+?()[\]{}|]/g,
           reHasRegExpChar = RegExp(reRegExpChar.source);

       return (string && reHasRegExpChar.test(string))
           ? string.replace(reRegExpChar, '\\$&')
           : string;
   };

   var flatten = function (array) {
       var newArray = [];

       array.forEach(function (item) {
           if (Array.isArray(item)) {
               newArray = newArray.concat(item);
           } else {
               newArray.push(item);
           }
       });

       return newArray;
   };

   function replaceString(str, match, fn) {
       var curCharStart = 0;
       var curCharLen = 0;

       if (str === '') {
           return str;
       } else if (!str || !isString(str)) {
           throw new TypeError('First argument to react-string-replace#replaceString must be a string');
       }

       var re = match;

       if (!isRegExp(re)) {
           re = new RegExp('(' + escapeRegExp(re) + ')', 'gi');
       }

       var result = str.split(re);

       for (var i = 1, length = result.length; i < length; i += 2) {
           if (result[ i ] === undefined || result[ i - 1 ] === undefined) {
               console.warn('reactStringReplace: Encountered undefined value during string replacement. Your RegExp may not be working the way you expect.');
               continue;
           }

           curCharLen = result[ i ].length;
           curCharStart += result[ i - 1 ].length;
           result[ i ] = fn(result[ i ], i, curCharStart);
           curCharStart += curCharLen;
       }

       return result;
   }

   function reactStringReplace(source, match, fn) {
     if (!Array.isArray(source)) source = [source];

     return flatten(source.map(function(x) {
       if (isString(x)) return replaceString(x, match, fn);
       
       const children = x.props.children;
       
       if (isString(children)) x.props.children = reactStringReplace(children);      
       
       if (Array.isArray(children)) x.props.children = children.map(child => reactStringReplace(child, match, fn));
       
       return x;
     }));
   }
   ```

   ```html
   <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/18.0.0/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
   <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/18.0.0/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>

   <div id="root"></div>
   ```

Мой вердикт - не используйте эту библиотеку, она очень не продуманная для сложных вещей

**Настоятельно рекомендую** найти другую библиотеку или же использовать `dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{__html: data}}`. Я лично обеими ручками за второй вариант :)

На самый худой конец, напишите свою более продуманную библиотеку вместо этой

Comment: Отлично, это то, что нужно)

Comment: @OliverPatterson Добавил ответ на второй вопрос

Comment: Может посоветуете аналог этой библиотеки? Текущий вариант не вызовет каких-то побочных явлений?

Comment: @OliverPatterson К сожалению мне нечего предложить взамен, никогда не пользовался такими вещами, а если нужно бывало то писал свои методы. Вызовет ли текущий вариант неожиданные результаты? Понятия и не имею Но суть ошибок в целом вы поняли, нужно рекурсивно уметь гулять по всем звеньям

Comment: Я получаю ошибку `Cannot assign to read only property 'children' of object '#<Object>'`

Comment: @OliverPatterson Если тут работает, то мне сложно сказать почему у вас ошибка. Наверное когда как библиотека вы это используете он внутри что-то да и блокирует. Я сюда просто из самой библиотеки скопипастил функцию

Comment: Я вынес в отдельный файл и сделать `export default` функции `reactStringReplace` и подключил эту функцию вместо функции библиотеки. Там, где должно делать какую-то замену на JSX, выскакивает данная ошибка. (обычный текст выводит)

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/142160/discussion-between-oliver-patterson-and-eziomercer).